# FancyBox error when triggering box more than once

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I'm using FancyBox in conjunction with Google Maps for the purposes of route planning; the user enters their post code and then chooses a hotel via a radio button:

```
<input type="text" name="post_code" value="" id="post_code" class="post_code"  />

...

<input type="radio" name="venue_id" class="button_1_0" id="radio_1_0" value="166" onClick="if (conditi&hellip;) { ... }" data-postcode="CV7 9HZ" /><div><h5>ANSTY HALL, COVENTRY</h5></div>

...

<div id="map_routes_button">
    <a class="fancybox button-link" id="button" href="http://local/bookings/maps/routes/3" title="Plan your journey"><img src="http://local/library/images/ui/journey-planner.gif" alt="Journey Planner" width="290" height="70" border="0" style="border: 0px;" /></a>
</div>

...

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".fancybox").on("click", function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: this.href,
        data: 's=' + s + '&e=' + e,
        success: function (data) {
            $.fancybox(data, {
                'padding': 0
            });
            initialize();
        }
    });
</script>
```

All of which works fine, until the user choses another hotel, at which point the FancyBox jQuery chokes straight after $.fancybox(data, {...

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new x.fn.init(e,t,r)}
>   has no method 'fancybox' 3:3363 $.ajax.success 3:3363 x.Callbacks.c
>   jquery.js:3074 x.Callbacks.p.fireWith jquery.js:3186 k jquery.js:8253
>   x.ajaxTransport.send.r

Google Maps is working fine, and the code I'm using here is being used elsewhere in the application, albeit without the connection to FancyBox.

Also, the post code variables are passing values in the first, second, and any number of attempts afterwards.

I have only one instance of both jQuery and FancyBox present in the page, which eliminates the most common explanation for this type of error.

I don't think Google Maps has anything to do with this, and that it's something to do with passing variable data to FancyBox itself, though my meagre jQuery knowledge comes to an abrupt halt at this point.

Comment: what does `initialize();` do?

Comment: It's the function that triggers Google Maps. It's presence makes no difference to functioning of FancyBox, or the error I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to destroy fancybox before reinitialize it. I had a similar problem some times ago and it solved my problem. Give it a try:

```
$(document).unbind('click.fb-start');
```

Comment: Hi Hyde, I tried placing that just before $(".fancybox") and then just before initialize(); but neither attempt worked.